# How to make items look more clickable on mobile?

Tags: mobile, buttons, click

I am designing a product detail page for an e-commerce site on mobile. Some of the products have different options with different prices and some of those options have sub-option. So at the end some products have up to 6 different prices. 
The attached design has already been approved but there are still concerns about the clickability of the boxes. My team wants me to add chevrons (>) beside the prices but since there is a lot info going on and there is not too much space I am not sure that is the best solution. Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I would not use chevrons next to numbers as (some) people may read that as a Greater Than or Less Than sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my first impressions (as a standard user), it's not immediately clear to me that these boxes are clickable.

I think a button would serve you well here, like so:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMUuJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want "clickability", give them a button for each option! That will have the best affordance of anything else you can do.

Here's a rough idea (you would probably want to make them more button-like):

[image: Edited screenshot with buttons]

Answer (score 0):

We are all familiar with Pricing Charts and understand the top row is the Header while the text below is the description. Can we change the headers? I know it's a "return to the past" design BUT how about make the headers (OPTION A1) look like rounded-edge buttons and NOT just rectangles with white text?

Am I going to get my Design Degree revoked for this 1990s solution?